# Atribuir valor a um Select pelo texto da opção via Webbrowser

Tags: delphi, navegador-de-internet

Preciso definir o valor de um campo **Select** de uma página que é carregada dentro do componente TWebBrowser no Delphi 7. Este procedimento consigo fazer em outros campos em que os valores são iguais aos textos das opções, mas em outro campo como são centenas de valores e o texto da opção do **Select** é diferente do valor, então não consigo. O Procedimento que estou precisando é como este abaixo:

```
function SelectOptionByValue(const ADocument: IDispatch; const AElementID,
  AOptionValue: WideString): Integer;
var
  HTMLDocument: IHTMLDocument3;
  HTMLElement: IHTMLSelectElement;

  function IndexOfValue(const AHTMLElement: IHTMLSelectElement;
    const AValue: WideString): Integer;
  var
    I: Integer;
  begin
    Result := -1;
    for I := 0 to AHTMLElement.length - 1 do
      if (AHTMLElement.item(I, I) as IHTMLOptionElement).value = AValue then
      begin
        Result := I;
        Break;
      end;
  end;

begin
  Result := -1;
  if Supports(ADocument, IID_IHTMLDocument3, HTMLDocument) then
  begin
    if Supports(HTMLDocument.getElementById(AElementID), IID_IHTMLSelectElement,
      HTMLElement) then
    begin
      Result := IndexOfValue(HTMLElement, AOptionValue);
      HTMLElement.selectedIndex := Result;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

O Procedimento acima só serve quando o texto da opção do campo **Select** é igual ao valor da opção. Por exemplo:

```
SelectOptionByValue(web.Document, 'fNaturalidade', DMCadastros.cdsClientesUF.AsString);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acabei de descobrir, um pequena mudança na linha da função para:

```
if (AHTMLElement.item(I, I) as IHTMLOptionElement).text = AValue then
```

Alterei apenas a propriedade "value" para "text"

Mesmo assim obrigado a todos!

Comment: Sim, desculpas.